# how to filter table data when selecting option in a select box using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, json

I have a table which has some user details. I have populated those data from JSON. At the bottom of the table , i have a select box which is provided for users who can select developer or tester to filter the table. For example,

Consider a table contains 10 rows. the first 6 rows contains developer details and the last 4 rows contains tester details. If a user select developer in the select box , then the table should display the rows, which contain information about the developer. how can i achieve this by using jquery ?

```
 <table class="tableData" border="1" frame="void" rules="rows">
          <tbody>
            <!--data comes from JSON file -->
          </tbody>
          </table>
    <select id="selectEngineer">
                <option value="anyone">Any One</option>
                <option value="Developer">Developer</option>
                <option value="Tester">Tester</option>
              </select>



    $("#selectEngineer").click(function() {
            $(".tableData tbody tr").show();
            if($("#selectEngineer").val.length > 0) {
                $("#selectEngineer tbody tr").filter(function(index, elm) {
                    return $(elm).html().toUpperCase().indexOf($("#selectEngineer").val().toUpperCase()) < 0;
                }).hide();
            }
        });
```

Comment: save yourself the trouble my friend. use the datatables plugin! http://www.datatables.net/ you can easily replace the search box in the example with a select element with whatever options your heart desires.

Comment: @r3wt no i want to write myself..  without using any plugins..

Comment: I figured as much, and in that case i can't help you.

Comment: @r3wt.. thats ok. thanks for suggesting to use datatables.net